# RegEx get exactly 2 numbers, even if its less

Tags: javascript, regex

I need an expression wich returns me a string with two numbers, even if I have inserted only one number. In that case fill it with a placeholder. Is that even possible with RegEx?

using javascript

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about regex and doesn't specify the necessary complementary tag (see regex tag description)

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info , http://regex101.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a regular expression, whatever the language, won't be enough for that.

But using an optional matching group, it's not that hard :

```
var m = str.match(/(\d+)\D*(\d+)?/);
if (m) {
    var number1 = m[1],
        number2 = m[2]===undefined ? defaultValue : m[2];
    // use your two numbers
} else {
   // invalid : not even one number
}
```